To share the profile of the user, I want profile page to show as a QR code on a page to share/print/download
I use code from an existing widget - changed it and now I get an error

Custom widget QRcodeWidge cannot be parsed

// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';

class KaiQRCodeRenderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const KaiQRCodeRenderWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.data,
    this.cornersColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width; 200.0, 
  final double? height; 200.0, 
  final String data; "https://www.example.com"
  final Color? cornersColor; "purple"

  @override
  State<KaiQRCodeRenderWidget> createState() => _KaiQRCodeRenderWidgetState();
}

class _KaiQRCodeRenderWidgetState extends State<KaiQRCodeRenderWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dimension = (widget.width != null && widget.height != null)
        ? widget.width!.clamp(0.0, widget.height!)
        : 100.0;

    return Container(
      width: dimension,
      height: dimension,
      child: QrImage(
        data: widget.data,
        version: QrVersions.auto,
        size: dimension,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        eyeStyle: QrEyeStyle(
          color: widget.cornersColor ?? Colors.black,
        ),
        gapless: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'm no coder, and neurospicy, (dyslectic an discalculie so challenging)
Tried chatgpt but had no luck
